# import csv file on Neo4J with a Mac: which path to use for my file?

Tags: macos, neo4j, cypher

I am a new user of Neo4J. I would like to import a simple csv file into neo4J with my Mac, but it seems I am doing something wrong with the path to my file. I have tried many different ways but it is not working. the only workaround I found is to upload it on dropbox....

please see below the code I am using/

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file://Users/Cam/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/node_attributes.csv" as line
RETURN count(*)
```

the error message is:

> Cannot load from URL
>   'file://Users/Cam/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/node_attributes.csv':
>   file URL may not contain an authority section (i.e. it should be
>   'file:///')

I already try to add some `///` in the path but it is not working.

Comment: added potential solution. but also, which neo4j version are you using and are you authenticated already, when you try to run the command? can you make other queries?

Answer (score 2):

If the CSV file is in your `default.graphdb/import` folder, then you don't need to provide the absolute path, just give the path relative to the import folder:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///node_attributes.csv" as line
RETURN count(*)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. i try the code you provided but I got this error message: Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/node_attributes.csv

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `neo4j-import` from the terminal:

Example from https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/

```
neo4j-import --into retail.db --id-type string \
             --nodes:Customer customers.csv --nodes products.csv  \
             --nodes orders_header.csv,orders1.csv,orders2.csv \
             --relationships:CONTAINS order_details.csv \
             --relationships:ORDERED customer_orders_header.csv,orders1.csv,orders2.csv
```

What is not working when you try

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///Users/Cam/Documents/Neo4j/default.graphdb/import/node_attributes.csv" as line RETURN count(*)
```

?

Comment: actually, that the magic of coding....i tried it again and now it works....whereas yesterday not. so thank you to asking me to try it one more time :-)